# SQL Order One Column By Value in Another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to order the results from SQL so that an indented BOM nests the values in the correct order. I got the "hard" recursive part done, but now getting the results to nest correctly is proving to be more problematic than I would have imagined. There do not seem to be any duplicates of this exact question in my rather extensive research thus far.

Here is my data:

```
+------+------------+-------+-----+-------+
| Root | Assemblys  | Items | Qty | Depth |
+------+------------+-------+-----+-------+
| Root | Assembly   | Item1 | 1   |     0 |
| Root | Item1      | Item2 | 3   |     1 |
| Root | Item1      | Item3 | 4.6 |     1 |
| Root | Item2      | Item4 | 1.5 |     2 |
| Root | Item2      | Item5 | 22  |     2 |
| Root | Item3      | Item6 | 6   |     2 |
+------+------------+-------+-----+-------+
```

What I'm looking to do is sort the columns so that one column follows the values from another column. Notice how Item1 has its assemblies moved to be right after it appears in the items row? I have tried to figure out how to use one column to sort another column, but so far no luck with anything I've tried.

```
+------+-----------+-------+-----+-------+
| Root | Assemblys | Items | Qty | Depth |
+------+-----------+-------+-----+-------+
| Root | Assembly  | Item1 | 1   |     0 |
| Root | Item1     | Item2 | 3   |     1 |
| Root | Item2     | Item4 | 1.5 |     2 |
| Root | Item2     | Item5 | 22  |     2 |
| Root | Item1     | Item3 | 4.6 |     1 |
| Root | Item3     | Item6 | 6   |     2 |
+------+-----------+-------+-----+-------+
```

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8789a/2)

Comment: What order is it supposed to be in?  Maybe I'm missing something but I'm not getting enough context from your question.  My assumption is that this comes down to a design flaw, not a query flaw.

Comment: I think you can do this ordering in `recursive CTE` which got you this result

Comment: The order is driven from the items column. So the assenbly should have all the sub assemblies (items) follow it. I want the assemblies col to sort itself by the presence of the same value in the items col. Does that make more sense? it's getting one col to organize itself based on values in another col.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE, something like this:

```
;with cte as (
   select *, cast([Item] as nvarchar(max)) as [path] from IndentedBOM where Depth = 0

   union all

   select i.*, c.[path] + '/' + i.[Item]
   from cte as c
       inner join IndentedBOM as i on i.[Assembly] = c.[Item]
)
select *
from cte
order by [path]
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8789a/13)</kbd>